# How to make sure win-builder builds my package with c++11?

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp, r-package

I'm trying to make my package ([code available here](https://github.com/Lobz/facilitation)) pass [win-builder](https://win-builder.r-project.org) tests so I can upload to cran. The package relies heavily in Rcpp and I use some things that require C++11 standard. But the [win-builder test results](https://win-builder.r-project.org/yoSLgCXpexPu/00install.out) keep showing a number of warnings like the following:

```
warning: delegating constructors only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

I tried to make a minimal test with the `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` example package, adding a few extended initializer list uses, and a Makevars file containig just the one line:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

but the minimal test works fine. You can see in the win-builder test results for the minimal test that it's compiling with `-std=gnu++11`, whereas my package is being compiled without that option:

Minimal test:

```
*** arch - i386
d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
```

My package:

```
*** arch - i386
d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"D:/RCompile/recent/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/lib/3.5/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -pedantic -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c Individual.cpp -o Individual.o
```

Why are they compiled with different options? I'm using the exact same `Makevars` file. Just in case it's relevant, I have these lines on my `DESCRIPTION`:

```
Imports:
    Rcpp (>= 0.12.14),
    Matrix,
    grid,
    animation
LinkingTo: Rcpp
Suggests:
    knitr,
    rmarkdown
Depends:
    R (>= 3.1.0)
License: GPL-2
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
URL: https://github.com/Lobz/facilitation
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

EDIT: I copied the above into the minimal test package's `DESCRIPTION` file to make them more similar, and the minimal test file still compiles properly with `-std=gnu++11`.

Note: I upload the packages to win-builder via `devtools::build_win()`.

Comment: You cannot change the fact that win-builder uses `g++ 4.9.3`.  Which has incomplete C++11 support, particularly on the library side.  End of story.

Comment: Thanks, @DirkEddelbuettel! any idea why my test compiles differently?

Comment: You should have linked more prominently to your source repo. At a first glance you are missing the `src/Makevars.win` file -- which would not happen if you used a proper package creation helper for which we document two different ones.

Comment: Thanks again @DirkEddelbuettel. I'm looking into it. I didn't know those existed. Might I ask who is "we" in this context and where can I look for this documentation?

Comment: Well how did you find Rcpp, and how did you manage not to find _e.g._ its vignettes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding in `DESCRIPTION`

```
SystemRequirements: C++11
```

This avoids the need of having to specify a custom `Makevars` for different platforms (e.g. `Makevars` for Unix + Solaris + macOS, `Makevars.win` for windows).

However, as @DirkEddelbuettel said, C++11 support on Windows exist; but, the completeness of the `C++11` implementation with `gcc-4.9.3` is problematic on the library side

Comment: C++11 support on Windows is not "shaky" and I never said so. You get what `g++-4.9.3` provides.  No more, no less.  We once had to backport something its C++11 library lacks.  As for adding the C++11 declaration in `DESCRIPTION`, I have always maintained that I prefer the `src/Makevars{,.win}` approach but preferences differ, and both work.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel revised. Sorry about that. Typing quickly in the union.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @coatless, I was looking for a solution like that. Also, it seems to work, where my attempts with Makevars and Makevars.win hadn't worked yet. My build report now shows the -std=gnu++11 option and the warnings are gone!